# UPSERT vs typical INSERT or UPDATE prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, prepared-statement

my system is having a database either `mySQL` or Oracle. I am writing a function to:

- Check data in the database if id exists,
- if data exists then do an `UPDATE` otherwise do an `INSERT`

My question is, is it efficient if I use `UPSERT` statement? Though i may still have 2 SQL string one for `mySQL` and one for Oracle.

Here is my current code so far:

```
public void insertOrUpdate(Report report) throws DBException {

        String id = getId(report.id);

        String update =
                "UPDATE delivery SET url=?, response=?, created_date=? " +
                        "WHERE id=?";
        String insert = "INSERT INTO delivery (id, external_id, desc, url, response," +
                " created_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                ps = con.prepareStatement(insert);
                int idx = 1;
                ps.setLong(idx++, report.id);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.externalId);
                ps.setLong(idx++, report.description);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.url);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.response);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.createdDate);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } else {
                ps = con.prepareStatement(update);
                int idx = 1;
                ps.setString(idx++, report.url);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.response);
                ps.setString(idx++, report.createdDate);
                ps.setLong(idx++, report.id);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while Inserting/Updating delivery ", e);
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            close(ps);
            returnConnection(con);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For Oracle you can just use a MERGE statement

Comment: @OldProgrammer but is that efficient rather than using my code?

Comment: Yes.  You are replicating functionality already available in the MERGE statement.

Comment: Why are you using [two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16983968/average-joe) to ask basically [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70123848/642706) with the exact same code sample?